# How do I force an instance to set all its properties?

Tags: swift

Lets say I have a struct or class as follows:

```
struct Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String     
}
```

and when I creates an instance of this Person, I must set the values of all the properties.

I need this for a struct which has a lot of properties and needs to set all. I should not miss any value. Later my plan is to get all properties as key-value pair and I will do this with Mirror(reflecting: self) on Person struct.

The solution I tried with the protocol

```
protocol ProtocolPerson {
    var firstName: String {get set}
    var lastName: String {get set}
}

func someFunction() {
    let tempFirstName = "John"
    
    struct Person: ProtocolPerson {
        var firstName: String = tempFirstName
        var lastName: String = ""
    }
}
```

Here I can force Person struct to have all properties but I can pass the outside value to set its values. Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: why don't you use a class ?

Comment: @Titouan same error, "Class declaration cannot close over value 'value' defined in outer scope"

Comment: “Here I can force Person struct to have all properties but I can pass the outside value to set its values.” I'm not sure what you mean by this. Can you explain with some code?

Comment: What is that error you are talking about ? You don't speak of it in the question.

Comment: @Titouan and sweeper, kindly look at the updated code in the question

Comment: It's still not clear for me what you are asking and your last edit is just strange where you define the struct inside (!) a function and added a protocol for some reason.

Comment: all I need is a way so that I can forcefully set the values of all the properties of my struct.

Comment: Then why isn't the answer below useful, could you elaborate? There are of course other ways to do it but if you don't like the answer below it is hard to understand what you would accept as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a constructor for given struct

```
struct Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}

let person = Person() // error
```

Comment: I have around 20 properties for my struct that's why looking for different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is suitable for the item you want or not, but for classes that have a large number of properties, I prefer to use Builder.

Step by step:

step1: create Build protocol for other struct and class implement this:

```
public protocol Build {
    
    associatedtype T = Self where T:Build
    
    /// buildWith: by call buildWith, you can set any properties.
    /**
        struct Sample: Build {
            var name: String = ""
            
            init() {}
        }

        let object = Sample().buildWith.name("Hessam").build()
    */
    var buildWith: QueryBuilder<T> { get set }
    
    init()
}

extension Build {
    
    public var buildWith: QueryBuilder<Self> {
        get {
            QueryBuilder(self)
        }
        
        set { }
    }
}
```

step 2: create queryBuild Which uses Build:

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
public struct QueryBuilder<C: Build> {
    public typealias Element = C
    
    private let _build: () -> Element
    
    // MARK: - lifecycle
    public init(_ build: @escaping () -> Element) {
        self._build = build
    }

    public init(_ base: Element) {
        self._build = { base }
    }

    // MARK: - helper function
    public subscript<V>(dynamicMember keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Element, V>) -> (V) -> QueryBuilder<Element> {
    {
        [build = self._build] value in
        QueryBuilder {
            var object = build()
            object[keyPath: keyPath] = value
            return object
        }
        }
    }
    
    /// build: call end set properties. for more detail see Build protcol.
    /**
        struct Sample: Build {
            var name: String = ""
            
            init() {}
        }

        let object = Sample().buildWith.name("Hessam").build()
    */
    public func build() -> Element {
        self._build()
    }
    
}
```

step 3: now change ProtocolPerson with Optional value:

my goal for Optional value: optional value for init without any parameter inside Person struct.

```
protocol ProtocolPerson {
    
    var firstName: String? {get set}
    var lastName: String? {get set}
}
```

step 4: last work just Person Struct implement Build Protocol and add constructor without any parameter:

```
struct Person: ProtocolPerson, Build {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var phoneNumber: String?
    
    // add init. Build protocol needed this
    init() {}
}
```

last Step: for create object from Person with Builder:

```
let person = Person()
.buildWith
.firstName("John")
.lastName("apple")
.build()
```

Using this method you give the value of each variable you want to build time and the other variables have their own initial value or nil

output:

[image]